# When exactly is Axios Promise resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, axios, es6-promise

I think I know the answer to the question, but I did not find any documentation on it, so I want to be sure I'm not missing out on something.

```
const prom1 = axios.get('/user/1').then(res => {
  /* do stuff with response */
  return res;
});
const prom2 = axios.get('/user/2').then(res => {
  /* do stuff with response */
  return res;
});
Promise.all([prom1, prom2]).then(() => setLoading(false));
```

In the example above, the `.then` of `Promise.all()` seems to **always** be executed after `axios.get().then()`. But is `prom1` really only resolved *after* the `.then()` of axios has been executed?

My understanding/guess:

```
axios.get('/user/1').then(...);
/* THOSE TWO ARE THE SAME */
const prom = axios.get('/user/1');
prom.then(...);
```

The reason the `.then()` from `Promise.all()` will always be executed **after** the `axios.get().then()` is that they are executed synchronous and therefore it matters which `.then()` is being called first?

I know I could alternatively always do:

```
const prom1 = axios.get('/user/1').then(res => res);
const prom2 = axios.get('/user/2').then(res => res);
Promise.all([prom1, prom2]).then(() => {
  prom1.then(...);
  prom2.then(...);
  setLoading(false);
});
```

But this would only be triggered after all the promises have been resolved and if there is some *compute-heavy* stuff going on in the `...`-codeblocks, I don't only want to start executing on them after all the API-requests have been responded to.

Comment: The last part of your question makes me guess that you're trying to solve some kind of problem which you're not asking about. This looks borderline like an XY problem. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Actually, I do not have a problem with my running code at all, it's just that I'm at the edge of my knowledge (fairly new to javascript and ReactJS) and while I see a potential race condition, I am not sure if it actually exists and if so, what the best practice to resolve it, would be. Additionally, I would like the code to be of _good style_ so others can work with it easily.

Comment: The last code snippet in your question shouldn't need `then` inside the `Promise.all` since the data from the promise is already available, use them by destructuring the `Promise.all`'s `then`'s param with something like `[res1, res2]`.

Comment: `Promise.all([prom1, prom2]).then(([res1, res2]) => {`

Answer (score 2):

> But is prom1 really only resolved after the .then() of axios has been executed?

`prom1` is the return value from the call to the `then()` method, so yes.

> The reason the .then() from Promise.all() will always be executed after the axios.get().then() is that they are executed synchronous and therefore it matters which .then() is being called first?

No. They are executed asynchronously. The promise returned by `Promise.all()` doesn't resolve unless and until all the promises in the array it is passed resolved. The order those promises resolve in doesn't matter.

Comment: The only thing missing from this answer is that `.then` returns a new Promise, which is no longer the original Axios Promise from `axios.get`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies!
@Quentin You're right, I was thinking about a specific case: If the last promise gets resolved and I'd call `promN.then(...)` above the `Promise.all().then(...)`, those would be executed synchronously and the upper `.then()` would be executed first or would both be executed _parallel_?
@EmileBergeron I did not know about that,thanks for the information!

Comment: @AskingAround they are async, meaning that if `prom1` takes longer than `prom2` to resolve (network delay, etc), `prom2`'s `then` will be called first.